# How does the OS access files stored on the hard disk?

Tags: files, superblock

I know the first thing the OS accesses on the harddisk is the superblock.

But then what?

Comment: The "hard disk" contains partitions. See the output of `mount -l -t ext4`, for example. Each file system type has its own driver, which understands the specific partition format. The '/' directory has a specific inode number (ext4 uses inode 2 as the root). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768371/why-is-root-directory-always-stored-in-inode-two

Comment: https://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/fs/filesystem.html https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/12_FileSystemImplementation.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OS relies on the kernel which in turn uses drivers for various file systems to read / write. The handling of files are abstracted away trough the drivers and system calls trough interfaces so that when you say `open("file.txt")` you do not need to know how the file is stored on the disk etc. There is a long range of file systems, each with their own way of handling things. Here is a generic snippet on the ext system.

---

Example by Ext.

1. **Blocks**: Disk is divided into *Blocks* of contiguous space.
2. **Block Groups**: Blocks are divided into groups.
3. **Inode**: A structured set of information about an entry such as a file, directory etc.
4. **Directory**: A list of inodes <–> names

Each *Block Group* has a table of inode structures that belong to the group.

---

Core layout:

```
                     Padding  1024 bytes
                 Super-Block  1 block          *
Block Group Descriptor Table  many blocks      *
                    Reserved  many blocks
           Data Block Bitmap  1 block          *
                inode Bitmap  1 block          *
                 inode Table  many blocks      *
                 Data Blocks  many more blocks *
```

---

**Super-block** holds information such as:

- Total number of inodes
- Total number of blocks
- Number of blocks in a group
- Number of inodes in a group

In addition to be stored in block group 0 redundant copies are stored elsewhere as backups (in case of corruption).

---

**Block Group Descriptor Table** is directly after the *Super Block*. It holds, amongst other things:

- Number of *Block Groups* in the partition
- Descriptor for each *Block Group*

Where each Descriptor contains information on where data structures for that *Block Group* is located.

---

**Block Group** holds, amongst other things:

- Block address where inode table start
- Number of directories in the group

**Bitmaps** holds information about use. `0` for unused and `1` for used.

---

**Inode** (Index node)

A inode structure does ***not*** hold:

- name
- file-data

An inode holds information such as:

- Type, Permissions, User, Dates, … Pointers to DATA

DATA for a file is saved in blocks. An inode holds information about which blocks the file occupies. This is done by pointers in the inode. There are more then one *type* of pointers. If we call a pointer to data PTR so as:

[PTR] Address to block with DATA

- 12 - Direct pointers:

  - [PTR] Address to block with DATA
- 1 - Singly indirect pointer:

  - [S_PTR] Address to block with list of PTR
- 1 - Doubly indirect pointer:

  - [D_PTR] Address to block with list of S_PTR
- 1 - Triply indirect pointer:

  - [T_PTR] Address to block with list of D_PTR

Numbers of pointers in one *block* is dependent on *block-size*.

- [See Direct/Indirect Block Addressing](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Direct.2FIndirect_Block_Addressing)

---

[**Directory**](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Directory_Entries)

A directory is an inode. Its data holds information about files. Each entry links a name and an inode. Each directory also has `.`, for it self, and `..` effectively linking to parent directory. These can not be deleted.

The Root Directory always have inode 2 on ext. Do `stat /` or `cd /; stat .` to see. It's `..` links to `.`

- [See special inodes.](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Special_inodes)

When a file is created, it is aromatically added to it's proper Directory.

---

Inode numbers are indexes. They are ordered indexes in the inode table to an inode structure. As inode structures are fixed in size one can calculate where a inode structure is located.

As the superblock has a *inodes_per_group* one can find the block group by:

```
block_group = (inode - 1) / inodes_per_group;
```

And after that find the index:

```
inode_index = (inode - 1) % inodes_per_group;
```

Read the structure and the links to data. Read the data.

#### debugfs

One can use `debugfs` to extract various information about the file system.

Make sure you do not use the `-w` flag if you care about the data.

Optionally create a small sample to play with.

```
truncate -s 2M test
mkfs.ext4 -F test
mkdir x
sudo mount test x
sudo chown me x
cd x
echo "Hello Disk" >hello.txt
mkdir a b c
echo "Hello Bee" >b/hib.txt
sudo unount x
debugfs test
```

Enter `?` for list of commands.

---

`debugfs: stats` (minified)

```
Inode count:              256
Block count:              2048
Reserved block count:     102
Free blocks:              953
Free inodes:              240
First block:              1
Block size:               1024
Fragment size:            1024
Group descriptor size:    64
Blocks per group:         8192
Inodes per group:         256
Inode blocks per group:   32
First inode:              11
Inode size:               128
Directories:              5
 Group  0: block bitmap at 18, inode bitmap at 34, inode table at 50
           953 free blocks, 240 free inodes, 5 used directories, 240 unused inodes
           [Checksum 0x055a]
...
```

```
debugfs:  imap hello.txt
Inode 12 is part of block group 0
    located at block 51, offset 0x0180
```

Other examples:
https://www.cs.montana.edu/courses/309/topics/4-disks/debugfs_example.html